# C# - Alternative to Dictionary<string, dynamic> for older versions?

Tags: c#, dynamic, dictionary, .net-3.5

I'm trying to implement a templating class that takes in a template ID and a Dictionary with the needed objects.

---

e.g.

```
public string GenerateMessage(string messageID, Dictionary<string, dynamic> values)
{
    string gameMessage = gameMessages[messageID];

    var template= new StringTemplate(gameMessage);
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        template.SetAttribute(value.Key, value.Value);
    }
    return template.ToString();

}
```

usage example

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
values.Add("city", london) // instance of City
values.Add("country", uk) // instance of Country
values.Add("user", user) // instance of User
string message = GenerateMessage("ID123", values);
```

---

Unfortunately I'm using Unity and it only supports a subset of .NET 3.5, which doesn't include dynamic!

---

I really don't want to have a `Dictionary<string, string>` where I have to specify all the values I need, I would like to offer the templates references to the whole objects so that they can I can change the templates around with more flexibility.

---

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `StringTemplate.SetAttribute` look like? That's at the heart of this question: how are these `dynamic` values being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `gameMessage` or `StringTemplate` is, however, maybe you can use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
public string GenerateMessage<T>(string messageID, Dictionary<string, T> values)
{
    string gameMessage = gameMessages[messageID];

    var template = new StringTemplate(gameMessage);
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        template.SetAttribute(value.Key, value.Value);
    }
    return template.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Does this mean I can populate the `Dictionary<string, T> values` with instances of different classes? Or does this still limit `values` to one class e.g. `Dictionary<string, City>`?

Comment: @RadiantHex: You can use it with any type (you could specify [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx#csharp_generics_topic4)). But yes, the type of the value must be the same type, you cannot mix it. However, you could use it with `object`. Pseudocode: `GenerateMessage<object>("1", new Dictionary<string,object>());`

Comment: Thanks for making it clearer! I've seen some examples using `object`, but not really much explanation and how it differs from using dynamic. I guess there are a few gotchas with it?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/01/25/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-object-keywords.aspx

Comment: Thanks! This ended up being exactly what I was looking for! :)